# SQLite Case Sensitive and Case Insensitive Search

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sqlite

I have **NSMutableArray** with **NSMutableDictionary** that carries a **SQLite** search result. I need to make a difference between case-sensitive and case-insensitive search.  If I read some topics here, they say SQLite by default returns a case-sensitive result.  And they suggest that you use **COLLATE nocase** to make a case-insensitive search.  Actually, with the following code, I get the same result with or without COLLATE nocase.  What am I doing wrong?

```
const char *sql;
if (checkButtonR5.state == 1) { // checkButtonR5 is a checkbox button.  If it's on, it tells a search will be case-sensitive.
    sql = "Select address,date,name,age,ID From data1a WHERE request LIKE ?";
} else {
    sql = "Select address,date,name,age,ID From data1a WHERE request LIKE ? COLLATE nocase";
}

sqlite3_stmt *statement; // outputFile is a file path
if (sqlite3_open([outputFile UTF8String], &connection) == SQLITE_OK){
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        //NSLog(@"It cannot connect the database file.");
    }
    NSString *bindParam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%",rqt];
    if(sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [bindParam UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK){
        //NSLog(@"Problem binding search text param.");
    } else {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *field0 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0); // address
            NSString *field1Str0 = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field0];
            NSString *str0 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", field1Str0];
            ...
            ...
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(connection);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: LIKE is case-insensitive.  You can make it case-sensitive with a [pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like).

Comment: (Note that LIKE is for pattern matching.  For simple selection of a matching value use IS.  Or use one of the other [expression forms](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) for range checks, etc.)

Comment: Okay.  That's what I thought.  Thanks, Hot Licks.

Comment: Note that you can use the `lower()` and `upper()` functions to perform case-insensitive matching with IS and other comparison operators.

Comment: What I have eventually ended up doing is use a method inside 'While' returning a boolean value if str0 contains a search phrase.